# Count cells in for loop

Tags: python, excel

I am working on my Python project and I'm stuck on a for loop. Basically, I need to conditionally count cells in a column (bank_account) where the cells are populated, omitting empty cells and cells starting with '00000'.

Here's part of the code:

```
sheets = vendor_list.sheetnames
NIP_col = locate_col(vendor_list, sheets[0], 'VTID05')
bank_account_col = locate_col(vendor_list, sheets[0], 'BKAC05')
vendor_list_data_dict = {"VTID05":[],"BKAC05":[]}

for y in range(100000):
    bank_account_item_ID = str(vendor_list['Sheet1'].cell(row=2+y, column=bank_account_col).value)
    if bank_account_item_ID != "None" and str(bank_account_item_ID).startswith('00000'):
        vendor_list_data_dict["BKAC05"].append(
               str(vendor_list['Sheet1'].cell(
                   row=2+y, column=bank_account_col).value).replace(" ",""))
    else:
        pass
```

Result I get is number of cells starting with '00000'. Why? How do I fix this to count only populated cells with bank account numbers, without empty cells and cells starting with '00000'?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is flawed. It should read:

```
if bank_account_item_ID != "None" and not str(bank_account_item_ID).startswith('00000'):
```

because you apparently want to ignore those cells.

You may also consider to
drop the else/pass branch.

Comment: when I put 'not' in front of 'str(bank_account_item_ID).startswith('00000'):' I get number of empty cells with the number of cells I'm interested in. Still does not work

Answer (score -1):

This is because your condition

```py
bank_account_item_ID != "None" and str(bank_account_item_ID).startswith('00000')
```

attempts to find those cells that start with '00000' and at the same time don't equal the string that is composed of the letters 'N', 'o', 'n', and 'e'. If stick to this code, I would recommend to replace this line with

```py
not (np.isnan(bank_account_item_ID) or str(bank_account_item_ID).startswith('00000'))
```

Comment: This requires numpy for a trivial operation without mentioning. I would not recommend this approach  to a beginner still struggling with comparatively easy constructs.